# Replace 2nd to last line -1 in vi

Tags: regex, unix, sed, vi

I am trying to replace the content of 2nd to last-1 line in sed. But I cannot get the addressing correct.

for example: in a file

```
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
```

I want to do:

```
    1
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
```

In vi it has to be something like: 2,$-1s/$/,/ but $-1 wont work. please suggest.

Comment: sorry, not a programming question. Voting to move to superuser.com. Good luck.

Comment: @Sumit Kumar Ghosh `:2,$-1s/$/,/` works just fine (vim 7.3.154 on Ubuntu 11.10)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
seq 5 | sed '1b;$b;s/$/,/'
1
2,
3,
4,
5
```

Answer (score -1):

you are close. you need a 'g' at the end of 's' commdn. in vim:

```
:2,$-1 s/$/,/g
```

will get the thing done.

Comment: Actually, `:2,$-1s/$/,/` works just fine (vim 7.3.154 on Ubuntu 11.10) - `g` is used when you want to do multiple replaces, so no need for that one here. See `:help :s_flags`.